# How to build SOAP client in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I am able to send requests to the web service using `javax.xml.soap.*`, I would like to covert the code to use `webServiceTemplate`.

- I am struggling with creating request and result objects. ([sample Ive found](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) is related to xml not SOAP)
- I am also wondering if there is any advantages of using
  `webServiceTemplate`    over `java.xml.soap`. If there is not am I doing it correctly? Given that I need to get connected to 20 web services.

The only service it has is `findEvents` as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:findEvents soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <request xsi:type="soap:Request">
            <!--You may enter the following 7 items in any order-->
            <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">?</apiKey>
            <country xsi:type="xsd:string">?</country>
            <resultsPerPage xsi:type="xsd:int">?</resultsPerPage>
            <currentPage xsi:type="xsd:int">?</currentPage>
            <sort xsi:type="soap:Request_Sort">
               <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
               <field xsi:type="xsd:string">?</field>
               <order xsi:type="xsd:string">?</order>
            </sort>
            <filters xsi:type="soap:ArrayOfRequest_Filter" soapenc:arrayType="soap:Request_Filter[]"/>
            <updatedSince xsi:type="xsd:string">?</updatedSince>
         </request>
      </soap:findEvents>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My code is as follows:**

```
try {
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory =
            SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection connection =
            soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    MessageFactory factory =
            MessageFactory.newInstance();

    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();

    SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
    header.detachNode();

    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

    SOAPFactory soapFactory =
            SOAPFactory.newInstance();

    Name bodyName;
    bodyName = soapFactory.createName("findEvents",
            "xsd", "http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php");


    SOAPBodyElement getList =
            body.addBodyElement(bodyName);


    Name childName = soapFactory.createName("findEvents");
    SOAPElement eventRequest = getList.addChildElement(childName);

    childName = soapFactory.createName("apiKey");
    SOAPElement apiKey = eventRequest.addChildElement(childName);
    apiKey.addTextNode("MYAPI");

    childName = soapFactory.createName("country");
    SOAPElement cid = eventRequest.addChildElement(childName);
    cid.addTextNode("UK");
    message.writeTo(System.out); //show message details

    URL endpoint = new URL("http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php");
    SOAPMessage response =
            connection.call(message, endpoint);

    connection.close();

    //SOAPBody soapBody = response.getSOAPBody();
    SOAPMessage sm = response;

    System.out.println("Response:");
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    sm.writeTo(out);


    String validSoap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> " + out.toString();
    System.out.println("It is ValidSoap: " + validSoap);  //ValidSoap message

    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Reader in = new StringReader(validSoap);  //reading character stream
    Document doc = null; //empty jDom document is instantiated
    doc = builder.build(in); //build the jDom document

    Element root = doc.getRootElement(); //Envelope
    List allChildren = root.getChildren(); //list of all its child elements
    System.out.println("Root is:" + ((Element) allChildren.get(0)).getName());
   listChildren(root);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**New Code**

```
  webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult
               ("http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php",source, result);



@XmlRootElement
public class FindEvents {
    @XmlElement
    Request request;

    public Request getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

}

@XmlSeeAlso(SortTicket.class)
public class Request {
    @XmlElement
    String apiKey;
    @XmlElement
    String country;
    @XmlElement
    int resultsPerPage;
    @XmlElement
    int currentPage;
    @XmlElement(name = "Sort")
    SortTicket sort;
    @XmlElement
    String[] filters;
    @XmlElement
    String updatedSince;

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getResultsPerPage() {
        return resultsPerPage;
    }

    public void setResultsPerPage(int resultsPerPage) {
        this.resultsPerPage = resultsPerPage;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    public SortTicket getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public void setSort(SortTicket sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public String[] getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(String[] filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    public String getUpdatedSince() {
        return updatedSince;
    }

    public void setUpdatedSince(String updatedSince) {
        this.updatedSince = updatedSince;
    }

}

public class SortTicket {
    @XmlElement
    String field;
    @XmlElement
    String order;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe this question is better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: alright thanks for your suggestion, I just posted on code review as well http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95633/need-to-convert-a-complete-code-of-javax-xml-soap-to-webservicetemplate

Comment: @NitzanVolman: It doesn't look entirely on-topic.  Be sure you've read Code Review's Help Center.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have generated DTO classes with Jaxb annotation you can create a marshaller  ,unmarshaller and create objects of the DTO classes (`SortTicket`,`Request`,`FindEvents`) and send the objects directly instead of using the xml request

```
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(findEvents);
```

Something like this you'll have to configure.

Create a marshaller

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.yourcontextpath" />
```

create web service template

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php" />
</bean>
```

and in some class's method where you want to send soap request inject `webServiceTemplate` using `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

public void sendSampleSoapRequest() {

   SortTicket sortTicket=new SortTicket();
   // set its values
   Request request=new Request();
   //set its values
   request.setSort(sortTicket);
   FindEvents findEvents=new FindEvents();
   setRequest(request)
   Object response=webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(findEvents);
 }
```

`marshalSendAndReceive` message uses the Jaxb marshaller to convert your objects (marked with JaxB annotation)to xml.So above your `findEvents` object will be converted to its xml from.

**Regarding your second point**
Advantages of using `webServiceTemplate` over java.xml.soap. : you don't have to create those SOAPElements manually you just create an object and send it instead of big code for manually handling it.
Since you'll have to connect to 20 different web services it will be much easier for you to create DTO objects and send them directly.You may need to modify my above samples a little.May remove the deault uri

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>
```

and while sending request give the URI request

```
Object response=webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri,object);
```

For sending it to multiple server

```
Object response1=webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri1,object);
Object response1=webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri2,object)
```

uri1 and uri2 can be different soap service And if you don't have the wsdl you can send xml with this method

```
sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(uri1,source, result);
sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(uri2,source, result);
```

Sending a uri in the *send* method over rides the default URI

For example check [this](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/tag/webservicetemplate/) also check the api [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html)

Comment: Thanks, but how about if I need to send request to more than one web services? or if I do not have their WSDL, how can I configure web service template in those cases?

Comment: @DanielNewtown
For sending it to multiple server
`Object response1=webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri1,object);`
`Object response1=webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri2,object)`
uri1 and uri2 can be different soap service
And if you don't have the wsdl you can send xml with this method
`sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(uri1,source, result);`
`sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(uri2,source, result);`

It depends on your requirement you'll have to write code logic depending upon your need.

Comment: would it ignore value of defaultUri then?

Comment: @DanielNewtown yes it will ignore default uri if you provide one in the method.you can refer to the doc as well http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html   See section 6.2.2

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried the code, but still have a few issues, I posted a new question please have a look at that thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430826/cannot-create-a-soap-client-using-spring