# Cannot create a SOAP client using Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jaxb

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845148/how-to-build-soap-client-in-spring),[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273355/why-does-jaxbcontext-need-to-be-told-specifically-about-a-class-that-is-already), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017146/jaxbrepresentation-gives-error-doesnt-contain-objectfactory-class-or-jaxb-index) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532493/how-to-configure-spring-ws-to-use-jaxb-marshaller) I try to create a SOAP client using Spring but I receive following exceptions.

I have following code

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" 
class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php" />
    </bean>
```

When I add following code it returns below exception

Code

```
   <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.project.sample"/>
```

Exception

```
   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.project.sample" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

And when I add following code it returns below exception

Code

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.project.sample.SoapMessage"/> 
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.project.sample.SearchResponse"/>
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

Exception

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.Class" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

Both classes have @XmlRootElement as following one

**SoapMessage**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SoapMessage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SoapMessage {
    @XmlElement(name="Username")
    private String username;
    @XmlElement(name="Password")
    private String password;
    @XmlElement(name="LanguageCode")
    private String languageCode;
    @XmlElement(name="ErrorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;
    @XmlElement(name="ErrorCode")
    private int errorCode;
    @XmlElement(name="AppVersion")
    private String appVersion;
    @XmlElement(name="Request")
    private Request request;
    @XmlElement(name="Response")
    private Response response;

    getters and setters
```

**SearchFlightsResponse**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SearchFlightsResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchFlightsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "SoapMessage")
    private SoapMessage soapMessage;

    public SoapMessage getSoapMessage() {
        return soapMessage;
    }

    public void setSoapMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) {
        this.soapMessage = soapMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HåkenLid I am tried to define Marshaller in two different ways but both return exception.

Comment: @DanielNewtown can you post the code for your SoapMessage and SearchResponse classes.

Comment: @SarfarazKhan question is updated

Comment: `SOAPMessage`is a class from the JDK. Could you be possibly mixing up imports? Is it included in the package being scanned? Also, does ´com.project.sample`really contain the JaxB objects?

Comment: @Victor I double checked it and am importing the correct one. Yes that package containts JaxB objects